# How To Wire Multiple Listener Style Beans With Spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I can't really find a neat way to do this in Spring - imagine I have a class which listens for messages:

```
@Component
public class MessageReceiver {
  private List<MessageHandler> handlers = new ArrayList<>();

  public void receiveMessage(Message m) {
    for(MessageHandler handler: handlers) {
      handler.process(m);
    }
  }

  public void registerMessageHandler(MessageHandler handler) {
    handlers.add(handler);
  }
}
```

Basically, I want to be able to define multiple `MessageHandler` beans and have themselves register with the `MessageReceiver` automatically. I'd prefer not to have to maintain a list of `MessageHandler`s somewhere - I'd simply like Spring to find any in the context (maybe annotated `@Bean` or `@Component`) and have them call the `registerMessageHandler()` method as part of the wiring process.

What would be the neatest way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using the event publishing mechanism already included in Spring?

`ApplicationEventPublisher` can be `@Autowired`, and Spring will connect any `@Component` that implements `ApplicationListener<T>` or method annotated with `@EventListener` if you use Spring 4.2 or newer.

This feature is used by various Spring components, like Spring security to broadcast events, for instance when users authenticate.

You can read about this [here](https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/11/better-application-events-in-spring-framework-4-2)

**Edit**
If you don't like to use the built-in message mechanism you can just build your own using the same auto detection principle.

The current version of Spring allows you to `@AutoWire` a list of beans based on type, If all your `MessageHandler` instances are beans then It would look like this

```
@Component
public class MessageReceiver {
    private final List<MessageHandler> handlers;

    @Autowired
    public MessageReceiver(List<MessageHandler> handlers) {
        this.handlers = handlers;
    }

    public void receiveMessage(Message m) {
        for (MessageHandler handler : handlers) {
            handler.process(m);
        }
    }

}
```

If you are using a version of Spring that does not support autowiring collections, then you should implement `ApplicationContextAware` to get a reference to the ApplicationContext, so you can call `getBeansOfType()` to get all the MessageHandlers.

Comment: I guess it could be made to work, but it's a bit of a hack and abusing the event mechanism for something it's wasn't meant to do. I think I'd prefer to maintain a list of handlers in a `@Configuration` bean, which is at least correct, if a bit of extra work.

Comment: If your handlers are know in advance, which it sounds like, they should  be singleton beans, which means you can get them from the Spring Context. Either by having an `ApplicationContextAware` `MessageReceiver` and look then up using `getBeansOfType`, or by `@Autowiring` a `List<MessageHandler>` into the `MessageReceiver`.  If handlers are ephemeral, then you probably need to register/de-register them in code.

Comment: Ah, I'd not seen the autowired collections - that seems to be pretty much what I want.